# Require_once prevent me to redirect PHP

Tags: php

I am creating a login page in php. I want to redirect user to auto page after they succesfully login. Since I am using pdo, I am using require_once to call pdo.php. However, this line of code prevent to to redirect the designated page. If I remove the require_once code, i can successfully back to index page after I hit cancle. The following code will take me to auto.php page

```
<?php

require_once "pdo.php";
require_once "bootstrap.php"; 

if ( isset($_POST['cancel'] ) ) {
    // Redirect the browser to game.php
    header("Location: index.php");
    return;
}

$failure = false; 


if ( isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['password'])  )   {

      if ( strlen($_POST['email']) < 1 || strlen($_POST['password']) < 1 ) {
        $failure = "User name and password are required";
      }


    else if (strpos($_POST['email'], '@')!== false)
    {

      $e = htmlentities($_POST['email']);
      $p = htmlentities($_POST['password']);

      $sql = "SELECT email FROM users
         WHERE email = '$e'
         AND password = '$p'";

      echo "<p>$sql</p>\n";

      $stmt = $pdo->query($sql);
      $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

      var_dump($row);
      echo "-->\n";
      if ( $row === FALSE ) {
         echo "Incorrect password";
      } 
      else {
        header("Location: autos.php?name=".urlencode($_POST['email']));
        return;
      }
    }
    else
        {
          $failure = "Email must have an at-sign (@)";
        }

}
?>
```

Comment: Probably because the file does not exist therefore the code stops to execute.

Comment: Check the logs. What's the error?

Comment: Have you tried to use `require_once` after `if (isset($_POST['cancel']))`?

Comment: The require_once after if (isset($_POST['cancel'])) will allow cancer button work, the page will be redirected to the index page. However, the send redirect (auto page) will still have the same issue since I need to call pdo to check user login credentials

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bootstrap issue. The bootstrap.php output some information that prevent the redirecting. I moved the require_once "bootstrap.php" below the header tag and solved the problem.

ps: also remember that the **header()** has to come before anything in the model (except for **session_start()** which can be present before the header).

Answer (score 0):

Check no output is sent by your php required files, by a blank space or line at end for example, any output sent to the brower block further redirection or any other headers, closing the php tag is not a best practice, especially because of this kind of issue

If this is not the problem, check you don't have error (parse or missing file), to show them all include this at top of your script

```
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',true);
ini_set('display_errors','stdout');
```